# What is causing the display JTextArea to fail to dispay text?

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextarea

I'm writing a program for a intro to Java class I'm taking for a semi easy credit and have over engineered every project so far.  However, I've hit a road block on this one.  When `getLib()` is called it should display `lib[index]` in the center JTextArea, but it fails to do so.  Running the same output to the console yields no issues.

The full program:

````
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MadLib {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField input = new JTextField(50);
    JTextArea display = new JTextArea(19, 50);
    JButton editor = new JButton("Open Editor");
    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    JButton help = new JButton("Editor Help");
    JButton run = new JButton("Start Game");
    JPanel option = new JPanel();

    String[] lib = {
            "plural noun",
            "number",
            "plural noun",
            "noun",
            "adjective",
            "plural noun",
            "adjective",
            "verb",
            "verb",
            "Proper Noun",
            "adverb -ly",
            "verb",
            "verb",
            "noun",
            "number",
            "number",
            "animal",
            "verb",
    };
    String[] story = {
            "You would not believe your ", // plural noun
            "\nIf ", // number
            " million ", // plural noun
            "\nLit up the ", // noun
            " as I fell asleep\n 'Cause they fill the ", // adjective
            " air\nAnd leave ", // plural noun
            " everywhere\nYou'd think me ", // adjective
            " but I would just ", // verb
            " and ", // verb
            "\nI'd like to make myself believe that planet ", // Proper Noun
            " turns ", // adverb -ly
            "\nIt's hard to say that I'd rather stay ", // verb
            " when I'm ", // verb
            "\n'Cause ", // noun
            " is never as it seems\n'Cause I'd get ", // number
            " hugs\nFrom ", // number
            " thousand ", // adjective
            " ", // animal
            "\nAs they tried to teach me how to " // verb
    };
    String fullStory = "";
    boolean enter;
    int index;
    String parse = "";


    public void displayStory() {
        for (index = 0; index < lib.length; index++) {
            fullStory = fullStory.concat(story[index]);
            fullStory = fullStory.concat(lib[index]);
        }
        display.setText(fullStory);
    }

    public void getLib() {
        input.setEditable(true);
        input.requestFocus();
        for (index = 0; index < lib.length; index++) {
            enter = false;
            while (!enter) {
                System.out.println(lib[index]);
                display.setText("\n" + lib[index]);
            }
            input.setText("");
        }
        input.setEditable(false);
    }

    public void setGame() {
        try {
            option.remove(save);
            option.remove(help);
        } finally {
            frame.add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            option.add(run, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            option.add(editor, BorderLayout.WEST);
            display.setEditable(false);
            display.setText("");
            frame.pack();
            input.setVisible(true);
            input.requestFocus();
            display.setVisible(true);
            frame.setTitle("Game");
        }
    }

    public void setEditor() {
        try {
            frame.remove(input);
            frame.remove(editor);
            option.remove(run);
            option.remove(editor);
        } finally {
            option.add(save, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            option.add(help, BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.pack();
            display.setEditable(true);
            display.setText("");
            display.requestFocus();
            frame.setTitle("Editor");
        }
    }

    private void parseInput() {
        String newString = "";
        story = resetArray();
        lib = resetArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < parse.length(); i++) {
            if (parse.charAt(i) == '<') {
                story = addElement(story, newString);
                i++;
                while (parse.charAt(i) != '>') {
                    newString = newString.concat((String.valueOf(parse.charAt(i))));
                    i++;
                }
                lib = addElement(lib, newString);
                i++;
            } else {
                newString = newString.concat((String.valueOf(parse.charAt(i))));
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] addElement(String[] currentArray, String newString) {
        String[] tempArray = new String[currentArray.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(currentArray, 0, tempArray, 0, currentArray.length);
        tempArray[currentArray.length] = newString;
        return tempArray;
    }

    public String[] resetArray() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    MadLib() {
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        option.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        display.setEditable(false);
        input.addActionListener(e -> {
            lib[index] = input.getText();
            enter = true;
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println(input.getText());
            System.out.println(lib[index]);
        });
        editor.addActionListener(e -> setEditor());
        save.addActionListener(e -> {
            parse = display.getText();
            parseInput();
            setGame();
        });
        help.addActionListener(e -> {

        });
        run.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Game running");
            getLib();
            displayStory();
        });
        frame.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(option, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        setGame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MadLib();
    }
}```
````

Comment: that entire method makes very little sense to me. you should learn to work with Listeners

Comment: `getLib()` has an infinite while loop. The GUI is frozen, therefore you will never see any GUI updates.

Comment: `setGame()` Other tips: 1) If this game needs to do things repeatedly, like move a BG, implement a Swing `Timer`. 2) Use a `CardLayout` to flip between the groups of components.

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

I thought this was interesting enough to rework.  Here's the GUI I came up with, starting at the initial state.

[image: MadLib GUI 1]

Here's the display after left-clicking on the Start Game button.

[image: MadLib GUI 2]

Here's the display after adding all the words.  After running about a hundred tests, I was lazy and just typed x for all the words.

[image: MadLib GUI 3]

## Explanation

I used the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern when creating this Swing GUI.  The pattern implies that you create the model first, then the view (GUI), then the controller.

In Swing, the MVC pattern means:

- The view reads information from the model
- The view does not update the model
- The controller updates the model and repaints / revalidates the view

There's usually not one controller to "rule them all".  Each `ActionListener` acts as its own controller and updates the model and view that it's responsible for.

### Model

I used angle brackets to denote where to place a word.  Not only does that make it easier to create the MadLib, but it also helps ensure that the word requests remain in synchronization with the text.

I created two model classes, the `MadLibModel` class, and the `WordType` class.  The `MadLibModel` class holds the various MadLibs.  I used the OP's MadLib as one hard-coded example.  You could have a text file of MadLibs, read them all, and choose one randomly for the game.  The `WordType` class is a convenient Java getter/setter class to hold the word type, start index, and end index of one of the angle bracket values.

### View

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I put the creation of the `JFrame`, the main `JPanel`, the start `JPanel`, the editor `JPanel`, and the display `JPanel` in separate methods.  This makes the code much easier for mere mortals to read and understand.

The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for my Swing applications.  The JFrame uses a default [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

The main `JPanel` uses a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to manage the other `JPanels`.

The start `JPanel` contains the Start Game `JButton`.  The start `JPanel` uses a [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

The editor `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` and contains a `JTextField` to type the word.  The `JLabel` text is taken from the MadLib text, and the Submit Word `JButton` processes the word into the MadLib text.

The display `JPanel` uses a `BorderLayout` and is shown when all the words have been entered.  The `JTextArea` is enclosed in a `JScrollPane` in case the MadLib text is longer than 19 lines.

### Controller

There are two controller classes, the `GameListener` class and the `WordListener` class.  The `GameListener` class starts the game and the `WordListener` class processes each word of the MadLib.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MadLibGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MadLibGUI());
    }
    
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    
    private JLabel wordTypeLabel;
    
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    
    private JTextArea displayArea;
    
    private JTextField wordInputField;
    
    private final MadLibModel model;
    
    public MadLibGUI() {
        this.model = new MadLibModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MadLib");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        
        panel.add(createStartPanel(), "start");
        panel.add(createEditorPanel(), "edit");
        panel.add(createDisplayPanel(), "display");
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createStartPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start Game");
        startButton.addActionListener(new GameListener());
        buttonPanel.add(startButton);
        
        return buttonPanel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createEditorPanel() {
        JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        editorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        wordTypeLabel = new JLabel("Dummy information");
        editorPanel.add(wordTypeLabel);
        
        wordInputField = new JTextField(40);
        editorPanel.add(wordInputField);
        
        JButton wordButton = new JButton("Submit Word");
        wordButton.addActionListener(new WordListener());
        editorPanel.add(wordButton);
        
        return editorPanel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createDisplayPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        displayArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);
        displayArea.setEditable(false);
        displayArea.setLineWrap(true);
        displayArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(displayArea);
        
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Select Another MadLib");
        button.addActionListener(new GameListener());
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void showEditorPanel(WordType wordType) {
        wordTypeLabel.setText(wordType.getWordType() + ":");
        wordInputField.setText("");
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "edit");
        wordInputField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    
    public void showDisplayPanel() {
        displayArea.setText(model.getCompletedMadLib());
        displayArea.setCaretPosition(0);
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "display");
    }
    
    public class GameListener implements ActionListener {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            model.startOver();
            model.setNextWordType(0);
            WordType wordType = model.getWordType();
            if (wordType != null) {
                showEditorPanel(wordType);
            } else {
                showDisplayPanel();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class WordListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String wordInput = wordInputField.getText().trim();
            if (wordInput.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            
            WordType wordType = model.getWordType();
            int startIndex = substituteWord(wordType, wordInput);
            
            model.setNextWordType(startIndex);
            wordType = model.getWordType();
            if (wordType != null) {
                showEditorPanel(wordType);
            } else {
                showDisplayPanel();
            }
        }
        
        private int substituteWord(WordType wordType, String wordInput) {
            String text = model.getCompletedMadLib();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(text.substring(0, wordType.getFromIndex()));
            builder.append(wordInput);
            int startIndex = builder.length();
            builder.append(text.substring(wordType.getToIndex() + 1));
            model.setCompletedMadLib(builder.toString());
            return startIndex;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class MadLibModel {
        
        private String originalMadLib;
        private String completedMadLib;
        
        private WordType wordType;
        
        public MadLibModel() {
            this.originalMadLib = createMadLib();
        }
        
        /**
         * <p>
         * This method should read a file of MadLibs into a <code>List<String></code>
         * and select one of the MadLibs at random. We're going to hard code one MadLib
         * as an example.
         * </p>
         * 
         * @return String containing one MadLib
         */
        private String createMadLib() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("You would not believe your <Plural Noun>\n");
            builder.append("If <Number> million <Plural Noun>\n");
            builder.append("Lit up the <Noun> as I fell asleep\n");
            builder.append("'Cause they fill the <Adjective> air\n");
            builder.append("And leave <Plural Noun> everywhere\n");
            builder.append("You'd think me <Adjective> but I would just <Verb> and <Verb>\n");
            builder.append("I'd like to make myself believe that planet "
                    + "<Proper Noun> turns <Adverb>-ly\n");
            builder.append("It's hard to say that I'd rather stay <Verb> when I'm <Verb>\n");
            builder.append("'Cause <Noun> is never as it seems\n");
            builder.append("'Cause I'd get <Number> hugs\n");
            builder.append("From <Number> thousand <Adjective> <Animal>\n");
            builder.append("As they tried to teach me how to <Verb>\n");
            
            return builder.toString();
        }
        
        /**
         * <p>
         * This method would select a random MadLib from the List.
         * </p>
         * 
         */
        public void startOver() {
            this.completedMadLib = originalMadLib;
        }

        public void setCompletedMadLib(String completedMadLib) {
            this.completedMadLib = completedMadLib;
        }

        public String getCompletedMadLib() {
            return completedMadLib;
        }
        
        public WordType getWordType() {
            return wordType;
        }

        public void setNextWordType(int startIndex) {
            String text = model.getCompletedMadLib();
            int fromIndex = text.indexOf('<', startIndex);
            if (fromIndex < 0) {
                this.wordType = null;
                return;
            }
            
            int toIndex = text.indexOf('>', fromIndex);
            if (toIndex < 0) {
                String message = "Unbalanced angle brackets";
                throw new InvalidParameterException(message);
            }
            
            String wordTypeString = text.substring(fromIndex + 1, toIndex);
            this.wordType = new WordType(wordTypeString, fromIndex, toIndex);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class WordType {
        
        private final int fromIndex;
        private final int toIndex;
        
        private final String wordType;

        public WordType(String wordType, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
            this.wordType = wordType;
            this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
            this.toIndex = toIndex;
        }

        public int getFromIndex() {
            return fromIndex;
        }

        public int getToIndex() {
            return toIndex;
        }

        public String getWordType() {
            return wordType;
        }

    }

}
```